# why android:background doesn't work for me?

Tags: android, android-layout, background

my layout file as bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".LimeText" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/file_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ***android:background="@color/red"***
        android:text="@string/untitled" />

    <ScrollView  
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/scroll"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:fadingEdge="none">

            <EditText
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/file_content"
            ***android:background="@android:color/white"***
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:capitalize="none" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

but no matter how do I change the background, the `EditText`'s background always stay on black and the '`TextView`'s background always be grey. the grey `TextView` is set before, #CCCCCC, but now I want to change it to another `color`, it cannot.

Comment: set color code to background like "#454545"

Comment: make sure that you have changed color code in color.xml

Comment: @Lihong Qiu if my given solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your color code file must be on this path.

```
res/values/colors.xml
```

with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <color name="edittext_color">#000000</color>
        <color name="text_color">#00FFFF</color>
    </resources>
```

and now use that in such a way.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:background="@color/edittext_color" />
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.